# Using utl_http & wallets on 12c: certificate validation failure

Tags: oracle, ssl, plsql, oracle12c

Hope someone can spot what I'm doing wrong as I'm going bald from this.

I have used utl_http & wallets to call https on 11gR1 without much trouble, but our new 12c installation is causing me a lot of grief.

I have tried importing the trusted certificate using both oracle wallet manager, and command line, without any success.
I know that oracle can be picky as to caching the wallet, so I have tried multiple new sessions without any luck.

I have downloaded the three neccessary certificates for *.presstogo.com, Geotrust SSL CA & Geotrust Global CA.

The command-line version of my building the wallet is  as follows:

```
orapki wallet create -wallet /oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237 -pwd test=1237 -auto_login  
orapki wallet add -wallet /oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237 -trusted_cert -cert "*.presstogo.com" -pwd test=1237  
orapki wallet add -wallet /oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237 -trusted_cert -cert "GeoTrust SSL CA" -pwd test=1237  
orapki wallet add -wallet /oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237 -trusted_cert -cert "Geotrust Global CA" -pwd test=1237  
orapki wallet display -wallet /oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237   
Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.1.0.1  
Copyright (c) 2004, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.  
Requested Certificates:   
User Certificates:  
Trusted Certificates:   
Subject:        OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US  
Subject:        CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root,OU=GTE CyberTrust Solutions\, Inc.,O=GTE Corporation,C=US  
Subject:        CN=GeoTrust SSL CA,O=GeoTrust\, Inc.,C=US  
Subject:        OU=Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US  
Subject:        OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US  
Subject:        CN=GeoTrust Global CA,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US  
Subject:        CN=*.presstogo.com,OU=IT,O=Press to go AS,L=Oslo,ST=Norway,C=NO,SERIAL_NUM=SJYpOHrRdCDHE8KZ6dRFGMJthOjs7-v3
```

Ok, lets test this. Login to sqlplus and run the following:

```
declare  
    lo_req    utl_http.req;  
    lo_resp   utl_http.resp;  
begin  
    utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support ( true );  
    utl_http.set_wallet ( 'file:/oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237', 'test=1237');  
    lo_req := utl_http.begin_request ( 'https://production.presstogo.com/mars/hello' );  
    lo_resp := utl_http.get_response ( lo_req );  
    -- A successfull request would have the status code "200".   
    dbms_output.put_line ( lo_resp.status_code );  
    utl_http.end_response ( lo_resp );  
exception  
  when others then    
    utl_http.end_response ( lo_resp );  
    raise;  
end;
```

DECLARE

*

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed

ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130

ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

ORA-06512: at line 6

For the record, It is worth noting that the following does work:

```
declare  
    lo_req    utl_http.req;  
    lo_resp   utl_http.resp;  
begin  
    utl_http.set_wallet ( 'file:/oracle/product/12.0.1/owm/wallets/test1237', 'test=1237');  
    lo_req := utl_http.begin_request ( 'https://www.google.be' );  
    lo_resp := utl_http.get_response ( lo_req );  
    dbms_output.put_line ( lo_resp.status_code );  
    utl_http.end_response ( lo_resp );  
end;  
/
```

*Help me Obi-Wan, you're my only hope.*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others.

According to Oracle Support only the certificate chain should be imported, not the end site certificate. 
In the example I used above, only import the following certificates into the wallet:

`Geotrust SSL CA` & `Geotrust Global CA`

**Do not import the *.presstogo.com certificate**

To quote Oracle support:

> The reason that the select is failing in 12c is that 12c does not want
>   to see the user cert in the wallet as a trusted cert.
>
> This was apparently not an issue in previous versions but removing
>   that cert from the wallet fixed the issue here.

This contradicts all information I have found online regarding the use of utl_http to connect to Https sites, and confused the hell out of me.

Hopefully this will help others in my situation.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thank you for providing direct information from Oracle Support. Is this information available on MOS?