# ORA-29024 Certificate validation failure

Tags: oracle, ssl, oracle11g

I'm at the end of my rope on this one. I have a DB server that connects to our web server locally. We are finally setting up SSL on the web server, something that should have happened years ago, but hasn't for I don't know what reason (nothing legitimate, that's for sure. In fixing this gaping security hole, a different problem has emerged: the utl_http requests are failing with an ORA-29024 error, and despite my efforts, I cannot make them succeed.

I have created a wallet with the certificate in it, including the entire chain with the providers. I have used both .cer files and p7b files. I have the set_wallet command set properly, and the entire process works with the self-signed certificates that I created on a test bed system and locally. I simply cannot get them to work with the actual valid certificate.

My Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.180417.  Here is my code:

Create the wallet:

```
mkdir c:\oracle_wallet
orapki wallet create -wallet "c:\oracle_wallet" -pwd xxxxxxxx -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet "c:\oracle_wallet" -trusted_cert -cert "c:\certificates\cert.p7b" -pwd xxxxxxx
```

Make the HTTP call:

```
begin
  UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:c:\oracle_wallet', 'xxxxxxx');
  ...lines that build up the URL variable
  results := utl_http.request(url);
  ...
end
```

Again, I've tried .p7b files with the full certification path, and Base 64 .cer files, with separate files for each level on the chain, and neither work. The certificate is valid in a browser, when I hit the exact URL that Oracle tries to get in a browser it is perfectly fine with it.  Here is the precise error:

[image: ora-29024 Certificate validation failure]

Is there any way I can get more detail on the error from Oracle? It's quite vague. Note: I am downloading the certificate from my browser using the exact URL that Oracle is hitting.

Comment: Sorry. Oracle Wallets are annoying. If you do `orapki wallet display -wallet "c:\oracle_wallet"`, does it list all the CAs in the chain as trusted certs?

Comment: Also, it sounds like your certs are in PKCS#12 format (.p7b, .cer). I think the `add` command only supports DER and PEM (.crt), and it really prefers a single cert at a time. You could either convert them, or take a look at the orapki `import_pkcs12` command. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/ASADM/walletmgr.htm#ASADM10628

Comment: I'll give that a shot tomorrow morning and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: @kfinity Running the 'display' command does make everything in the certificate chain appear as trusted certificates.  I tried the 'import_pkcs12' command and it was not recognized by my version of orapki (11.2.0.4.0). I have tried importing the certificates individually in the base 64 format, and that was unsuccessful as well.

Comment: That seems like it should work. Hmm. This question for 12c suggests *not* importing the site certificate into the wallet as a trusted cert, only the CAs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380116/using-utl-http-wallets-on-12c-certificate-validation-failure

Comment: I've read that about 12c, but the recommendation for 11g is the entire chain.