# ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP"

Tags: oracle, validation, web, https, certificate

I got

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP"
```

while trying to get web page from site using https.
I imported certificate from site into wallet

```
Oracle PKI Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
Subject:        C=UA,ST=ua,L=kyiv,O=test,OU=test,CN=test
User Certificates:
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=extremstyle.ua
```

Then run this block

```
declare
 req utl_http.req;
 resp utl_http.resp;
begin
 utl_http.set_wallet('file:C:\OracleSoftware\admin\db1\dpdump', '*******');  -- here real password
 req := utl_http.begin_request('https://extremstyle.ua/');
 utl_http.set_header(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
 resp := utl_http.get_response(req);
 utl_http.end_response(resp);
end;
/
```

What should I do or check also?
I've read a lot of topics about this here, but still haven't got any idea ...

Comment: Where do you got the certificate from? Are you sure the domain name is inckluded in the subjectAlternativeName extension, not only in the subject of the cert?

Comment: I got it from browser on web site, where can I check it? In properties on site: DNS-name: extremstyle.ua

Comment: You may need to add the intermediate (and possibly even root) certificate to your wallet as well. Or actually, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527985/266304), *only* those - not the actual web page certificate.

Comment: It is does not help at all : Oracle PKI Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
Subject:        C=UA,ST=ua,L=kyiv,O=test,OU=test,CN=test
User Certificates:
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA,O=Sectigo Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
Subject:        CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority,O=The USERTRUST Network,L=Jersey City,ST=New Jersey,C=US
Same error Certificate validation failure

Comment: Seems that it works now! Maybe was need to reconnect. Thanx guys!

Comment: You need to import only root CA certificate and label is as trusted. Other certificates will be sent to you by server. Install Wireshark, eavesdrop the communication and you will see what is going on.  Wireshark will give you more diagnostic information than Oracle.

Comment: @Robert your statement does not make much sense. The certificate with subjectAlternativeName (SAN) is what you get fom the web server when you call the website. What you need to store in the Wallet is the CA certificate in oder to validate the server certificate. Typically a CA certificate does not have any SAN, it would be useless.

Comment: @ibre5041 Maybe a bit overkill to install Wireshark. OpenSSL is fully sufficient to see, analyze and verify certificates. BTW, you can use OpenSSL also to open Oracle Wallet file which is a standard certificate store.

Comment: Thanx to all for response.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Oracle uses MES from RSA BSAFE, which is alternative SSL implementation to OpenSSL. Oracle declares it supports TLS1.2 (even TSL1.3) but ... set of cypher suites is little bit different from OpenSSL. They understand TLS bit differently.
So while opening SSL connection you might see strange errors, due to some missing features in MES. OpenSSL is suitable to analyze certificates, WireShark is useful  to analyze TLS negotiation. I was using it when I had problem to authenticate using client cert.

Comment: @ ibre5041  Maybe I use your advise when/if got nerwork errors, thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is an amazing technology. Sometimes it gives proper page, sometimes torn in some way, sometimes it raises

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29263: HTTP protocol error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 837
ORA-06512: at
"SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1350
```

I can't see any dependense.
Fantastic!

```
SQL> select status from v$encryption_wallet;

STATUS
------------------------------
CLOSED

SQL> administer key management set keystore
  2  open identified by "***";
administer key management set keystore
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28353: failed to open wallet

SQL> alter system set encryption wallet open identified by "***";
alter system set encryption wallet open identified by "***"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28353: failed to open wallet

C:...\Scripts>mkstore -wrl C:\OracleSoftware\admin\db1\dpdump -list
Oracle Secret Store Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Enter wallet password:
Oracle Secret Store entries:
oracle.security.client.connect_string1
oracle.security.client.password1
oracle.security.client.username1
```

From Oracle Docs: Oracle Wallet provides an **simple and easy** method to manage database credentials across multiple domains